# Adding multiple key:value pairs to DynamoDB to existing map?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

Let's say I have an item in the test table in DynamoDB like this:

```
test: {
    {
        id:'100',
        page:'#test',
        general: {
            foo: 'super_foo',
            bar: {
                    item:'string_item'
                }
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to find a way to make it end up like:

```
test: {
    {
        id:'100',
        page:'#test',
        general: {
            foo: 'super_foo',
            bar: {
                item:'string_item'
                },
            bbb: { 'bbbb':'cccc' },
            ccc: 'dddd'
        }
    }
}
```

I tried the following (in python, using boto3):

```
table.update_item(
        Key = {
            'id': '100',
            'page': 'page_name'
        },
        UpdateExpression= "set #g=:r",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':r': { 'bbb': { 'bbbb':'cccc' }, 'ccc': 'dddd' },
        },
        ExpressionAttributeNames = {
            '#g': 'general'
        },
)
```

...but it only erased the items I already had:

```
test: {
    {
        id:'100',
        page:'#test',
        general: {
            bbb: { 'bbbb':'cccc' },
            ccc: 'dddd'
        }
    }
}
```

Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 2):

Please try the following:

```
table.update_item(
    Key={
        'id': '100',
        'page': '#test'
    },
    UpdateExpression="SET #general.#bbb = :bbb, #general.#ccc = :ccc",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={':bbb': {'bbbb':'cccc'}, ':ccc': 'dddd'},
    ExpressionAttributeNames={'#general':'general', '#bbb':'bbb', '#ccc':'ccc'}
)
```

Note that DynamoDB interprets a dot in an expression attribute name as a character within the attribute's name (as opposed to a separator between levels of a hierarchical attribute's name), so you can't simply set an ExpressionAttributeNames value of `general.bbb`. Instead, you need to define an expression attribute name for *each* element in the document path (so `general` and `bbb` independently).

Comment: Sorry, I'm so stupid. I've updated with what I'm actually looking for.